# Is there a method to constrain objects relative to other objects in three.js

Tags: three.js

Is there a simple method to constrain objects to each other in three.js. For example; if I make a table with 4 legs I would like to create the objects: (a top and a leg) and be able to add the top and 4 legs to the scene and make the top of the leg attach to the underside of the table top and offset the faces of the legs from the edge of the top.  If anyone is famiar with the 'fully constrained' principle from inventor I would ideally like to achieve this, such that I could change table height or top thickness etc and have the leg length updated automatically.
Thanks

Comment: Ok so I've found the constraints section of Physijs which seems to do a lot of what I require https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/wiki/Constraints

Comment: you can create the table and then add the legs to the table as children. For example: table.add(leg_1);

Answer (score 1):

To rephrase your example, you would like to attach four legs to the bottom of the table slab, but have their length automatically track any changes you might make to the position of the top of the slab, or its vertical thickness.

Every THREE.js object is descended from `THREE.Object3D` and thus has access to `EventDispatcher` methods (listed in the TRHEE docs). This means that with a bit of fiddling, you can indeed have these sorts of automatic relationships. But you'll need to define and manage the relationships between events -- that is, if you want the legs to listen for changes in the dimensions of the tabletop slab, you'll need the slab to emit the appropriate event and the legs to hear it (or both to listen to some higher invisible group object or constraint manager). A listener-based scheme is pretty much how Inventor does it, too. It's under the hood in tools like Inventor (or Maya, etc) while in THREE you'll need to use your own wrench.